# hide rowtable cell android

Tags: android, tablelayout, tablerow

I have a table layout and I load in dynamically rowtable by rowtable from DB.

I want to know if is it possible to hide a cell in rowtable or hide a column in table layout?

and another thing, how can I get a data from a cell in rowtable ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can hide a column using setColumnCollapsed(int index, boolean isCollapsed)...check out the api.

Comment: Also, if this was what you were looking for can you please mark the question answered? :)